# Getting XML from official site from JQUERY code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to get currencies rate from the URL:
[CURRENCY](http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml?curr=01)

It works perfect from browser and also from Android java using REST API.
Now I'm trying to get it from JS using JQUERY AJAX.

I use this code:

```
function handleJson(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml?curr=01?jsoncallback=handleJson',
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    success: function(result) {
            alert("XML File is loaded!");
            alert(result);
            },      
        async: true,
        dataType:"jsonp",
        type:"get"
});
```

I see in the log that content arrives but I can't handle it.
Here the screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well, your dataType should be xml not jsonp I should imagine.

Comment: When I use XML I get:  
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: if API doesn't return jsonp you can't force it to do so. Unless API is CORS enabled or jsonp enabled you will have to use a proxy